# Vimeo uiwebview privacy settings

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, vimeo, vimeo-player

I am developing an app, to play private videos from vimeo by making use of uiwebview by embeding the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type=\"text/css\">
body {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style=\"margin:0\">
<iframe src=\"//player.vimeo.com/video/{VIDEO_NAME}?title=0&autoplay=1&amp;loop=1\" width=\"1000\" height=\"420\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>"
```

This will play all public vidoes from Vimeo. Now I want to make my videos private by providing username and password. From app side how can I pass username and password to Vimeo?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking. What username and password are you trying to pass? The user's Vimeo login credentials? Or, your Vimeo login credentials so they can access your video?

Either way, that's not the way to go.

Comment: I wanted to play private video from vimeo by making use of iframe, after searching for lot time its clear that we cannot pass any credentials in the URL to load it via Iframe, anyways thanks for your response.

Comment: https://github.com/satishVekariya/LXVimeoKit